# Is it possible to get ota updates after making system rw?

Tags: updates, ubuntu-touch, sudo

Is it possible to get ota updates after making system rw by "sudo mount -o remount,rw /"?
I mean in this case: If I don't update system using "sudo apt-get update" and don't install any software using terminal. Only copy new ringtones to appropriate folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add & modify files in RW mode, and then do an OTA update, yes.

However we never test this scenario, so if it doesn't work, or the files disappear, you'll probably need to cleanly re-flash the device to 'reset' back to a working state.

Comment: Just to make sure - is it possible to put the system in RW mode, copy a new ringtone, and put the system back into RO mode?

Comment: @Stunts - yes it is possible - after the next phone restart the filesystem will be back in read-only mode again.